# Separating script, style and template in Vue.js and Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vue-router

I'm creating a large scale application with amazing **Vue** and **Webpack**.
I don't want to have *.vue* files since I want to separate them to something like `comp.js`, `comp.pug` and `comp.styl`

my `comp.js` will be:

```
export default {
    template: require('./comp.pug'),
    data: () => {
        return {
            compStyle: require('./comp.styl');
            message: 'Hello World!'
        }
    // ...
    },
}
```

my `com.pug` will be:

```
div#comp(v-bind:style="compStyle")
    h1.heading {{ message }}
```

And finally my `comp.styl` will be:

```
.heading
    color: #6E6E6E;
    background-color: #E6E6E6
    text-align: center
```

In first glance everything seems fine till I try using **VueRouter** and of course elements like `<router-link />` or `<router-view />`!

Since I wont have any *.vue* file, I'd assume having `alias: { 'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js' }` in Webpack wont help me!

How can I overcome this issue?

BTW, that the error I get in the console is:

> [Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the
>   template option is not available. Either pre-compile the templates
>   into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

---

### Update

Worth to mention that I have two entry files:
One for whole application

```
import MainComp from './comp/main';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

new Vue(MainComp).$mount('#app');
```

And one for components (sub components are as above):

```
import Router from './route';
import SubComp1 from './sub1.comp'
import SubComp2 from './sub2.comp'

export default {
  template: require('./main.pug'),
  router: Router,
  components: {
    SubComp1,
    SubComp2
  }
}
```

My `main.pug`:

```
div
    | here goes the views
    router-view
```

And here is my `route.js`:

```
export const Router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/three', component: SubComp3 },
    { path: '/Four', component: SubComp4 },
    { path: '/', redirect: '/' }
  ]
})
```

So when I have `alias: { 'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js' }` added to my webpack, error(s) will be something else:

> [Vue warn]: Error when rendering root instance
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'matched' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

component.vue (with vue-loader):

```
<style src='./style.styl'></style>
<template src='./template.pug'></template>
```

Make sure, that loaders for *.styl, *.pug exist.

**UPDATE:**
I'm forget, than you can do it like this (without vue-loader):
component.js

```
import './style.styl'
import tmpl from './template.pug' // may be it will work

// if import doesn't work, then do it with string variable in this file or import
const tmpl = `
   h1 Hello world
`

export default {
   template: tmpl,
   data() {
      return {}
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alex! As I also commented out for Carig, for now I'd rather to don't go with the src imports as still need to add `.vue` files, `vue-loader` and etc :)

Comment: Just use vue-cli and forget about pain. Command: vue init webpack project_name.  Link: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I did use the `vue-cli` and tried out almost all templates! Still all of them provide `.vue` files... Also thanks for the updated answer. That's already what I'm doing with some minor changes, but still have the issue... Decided to make some major changes there :) Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

`Vue-loader` compiles `.vue` files into `render functions`, if you are not using them then you are going to need to use the `standalone-build` which includes the template compiler. As far as I'm aware that is the only difference between the `runtime` and `standalone` builds, so I see no reason why using the `alias` for the `standalone build` would not work in your case.

Incidentally, `.vue` files can be split into multiple files. Take a look at the **src imports** section on [this page](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/start/spec.html), to see if it's something that would suit the requirements of your project

Comment: Thanks for your answer @craig_h! For now I'd rather to don't go with the src imports as still need to add `.vue`s, `vue-loader` and etc! I Have updated my question... Maybe you have answer for the updated version as well